# Linux application to monitor the power consumption

Tags: power-management

Is there a tool/app available in Linux/Ubuntu or other distribution, to monitor how much Power is being consumed by the computer (in this case a Dell XPS 15 9510 laptop) from the USB-C/TB 4 port.

It would be good to have Volts and Amps as well. Thanks

Comment: There are power bars that can give you this information. Your question is about hardware not the OS.

Answer (score 0):

To name a few - [Powertop](https://linoxide.com/install-use-powertop-ubuntu-16-04/); [Powerstat](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/powerstat.8.html) and [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/)